# Hard coded email field for participants when using the event cart system

Tags: civievent

Why is there a hard coded email field for participants when using the event cart system? This is causing issues with duplicates (duplicates unless the rule is only checking email). If the contact does not exists - it's fine, but if the contact does exist it attaches the payment to the existing contact and the participant to a new (duplicate) contact. If the profile for the event has an email field, there are now two email fields.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5db0bc3c1f54eaca4307f103a73bda596ae914d6/ext/eventcart/templates/CRM/Event/Cart/Form/Checkout/Participant.tpl#L14

Comment: Also having this problem. I would be curious to know any possible solutions!

Comment: This may be an inappropriate comment but I haven't heard of Event Cart being used much - and for sites on Drupal CMS i expect those who do need abiilty to purchase multiple events is done via Webform

Comment: also in case this is of any use, we did an extension that allows you to set one event as the parent, and other events as child events, so that someone who registers for the parent event gets signed up for all the child events